# Reducing the length of if statement in swift

Tags: ios, swift, if-statement, swift3, conditional-statements

I've got an application with 3 screens, screen 1 (categories) has a number of buttons, screen 2 (details) has more buttons and screen 3 displays text based on what button was pressed in the previous 2 screens.

The buttons on screen 1 stay the same, the buttons on screen 2 vary with some hidden or shown depending on which button was pressed on the first screen. To that end, I now have a very long if statement and I'm trying to find ways of reducing it.

Can help but think I'm missing something simple.

If statement looks similar to this:

```
if selectedCategory == "Option 1" {

        if selectedDetail == "Detail A" {

            selectedURL = optionOneData.detailA

        } else if selectedDetail == "Detail C" {

            selectedURL = optionOneData.detailC

        } else if selectedDetail == "Detail E" {

            selectedURL = optionOneData.detailE

        } else if selectedDetail == "Detail G" {

            selectedURL = optionOneData.detailG

        } else if selectedDetail == "Detail J" {

            selectedURL = optionOneData.detailJ

        } else {

            print("Invalid selection, something went wrong.")

        }

    } else if selectedCategory == "Option 2" {

        if selectedDetail == "Detail B" {

            selectedURL = optionTwoData.detailB

        } else if selectedDetail == "Detail C" {

            selectedURL = optionTwoData.detailC

        } else if selectedDetail == "Detail D" {

            selectedURL = optionTwoData.detailD

        } else if selectedDetail == "Detail E" {

            selectedURL = optionTwoData.detailE

        } else if selectedDetail == "Detail F" {

            selectedURL = optionTwoData.detail F

        } else if selectedDetail == "Detail G" {

            selectedURL = optionTwoData.detailG

        } else if selectedDetail == "Detail H" {

            selectedURL = optionTwoData.detailH

        } else if selectedDetail == "Detail I" {

            selectedURL = optionTwoData.detailI

        } else if selectedDetail == "Detail J" {

            selectedURL = optionTwoData.detailJ

        } else {

            print("Invalid selection, something went wrong.")

        }
```

Not my actual code, renamed variables for context.

This only represents about 1/3 of what I have so I'm keen to reduce the amount of code used to be more efficient and readable.

Thanks.

Comment: `Switch()` statements are the replacement of long `if-elseif-else` conditional statements. Try using it.

Comment: Also create your option as `Enum` will make your code much more readable, still you have to use `switch` to assign data and string

Comment: A switch statement would still be quite lengthy, your data could probably be saved in a dictionary or array quite easily.

Comment: The `selectedCategory == "Option 1"` condition doesn't make any sense, because you can make all the `if/else` statement without check it too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `switch()` statement as:

```
var selectedCategory = ""

switch selectedCategory {

    case "Option 1" :
    var selectedDetail = ""

    switch selectedDetail {

        case "Detail A"
        selectedURL = optionOneData.detailA

        case "Detail C"
        selectedURL = optionOneData.detailC
        ....

        default:
        print("Invalid selection, something went wrong.")
   }

 case "Option 2":
 var selectedDetail = ""

 switch selectedDetail {

       case "Detail A"
       selectedURL = optionOneData.detailA

       case "Detail C"
       selectedURL = optionOneData.detailC
       ....

       default:
       print("Invalid selection, something went wrong.")
 }

 default:
       print("Invalid selection, something went wrong.")
}
```

Comment: Note you could use a single switch on the tuple e.g. `switch (selectedCategory, selectedDetail) { case ("Option2", "DetailA"): ...`

Comment: Opted for Switch in the end, it reads better and on reflection if I ever wanted something else to run when these buttons are pressed this is probably (I think) the best way of doing it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Keep all your selecting detail and its url in dictionary, like this

```
let selectionInfo = ["Detail A": optionOneData.detailA, "Detail E": optionOneData.detailE]
```

and use this to get selected url.

```
selectedURL = selectionInfo[selectedDetail]
```

if selectedURL is nil, then there is no valid selection.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see in your code a `Switch()` statement would be the best for you, instead of using this long `if-else` statements. It's a best practice in this situations.